# Remedies for a Gṛhastha for involving in sex on auspicious days

Tags: scripture, sex, prayaschitta

Answers of [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/44123/17363) says Gṛhastha rules of the days one should not involve in sex.  If a Gṛhastha involves in sexual activities on these following days, then what are the remedies one can follow?

Comment: If you indulge in sex on days which are NOT allowed, as penance, do not indulge in sex on days when it IS allowed. Of course goes without saying to not indulge in sex on days which are not allowed.