# Today I took an oil bath (abhyangana snana on Amavasya). What does it mean? With parents? or does shastras describe the consequences of such action?

Tags: rituals, customs

I there is already question about abhyangana snana. But I for someone who took a oil bath by negligence. What does it mean? Or if i gave a oil bath to my kid on Amavasya. what does it mean? Are there scriptures about such acts or yes days and no days for oil bath?

Comment: As per Vyasa Niti (found in Brahma Purana), Amavasya is one of the prohibited days for taking oil bath. See [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44150/4732)

Comment: Please edit your question. Otherwise it has an element of personal advice.